# Conferences about political meritocracy?

Tags: reference-request, meritocracy

In his book, The China Model, Daniel Bell refers to conferences about political meritocracy:

> In a (selfish?) effort to help further my own thinking, I coorganized two conferences with leading philosophers, historians, and social scientists that examined the rise (or revival) of political meritocracy and what it will mean for political developments in China and the rest of the world.

What's the name of these conferences?

Answer (score 2):

One most certainly is [ideacity: subtile: The China Model: Political Meritocracy and the Limits of Democracy
Daniel A. Bell](https://vimeo.com/122753058), hosted in Toronto 3 years ago.  The second is most likely ['Democracy, Meritocracy, or Both' with Daniel Bell (CASBS fellow, 2002–03; CASBS research affiliate, 2015–16) and Nicolas Berggruen, from the 2015 Symposium](https://casbs.stanford.edu/events).

[Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BS130QDg6Fw)

Small caveat: his bio does mention that he's a regular participant at World Economic Forum meetings in Davos and China.